# Can I return a value from a mex-file even when nlhs==0 to be consistent with m-file behavior?

Tags: matlab, mex

I noticed some differences on how is managed the *most recent answer* display when using `m-code` versus using `mex-code`. Here some simple code to show the issue:

#### m-code

Suppose one has the following matlab routine:

```
function [v] = foo()
%[
    v = 42.0;
%]
end
```

If on matlab prompt one types `>> foo()`, then one obtains `ans = 42` and if one types `>> foo();` there is no display ... **so far, so good** ...

#### mex-code

Now suppose the following equivalent routine as a `mex` function:

```
[mfoo.c]
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{ 
    mexPrintf("There are %d left-hand-side argument(s).\n", nlhs);

    if (nrhs > 0) { mexErrMsgTxt("Too many input arguments."); return; }
    if (nlhs > 1) { mexErrMsgTxt("Too many ouput arguments."); return; }
            
    if (nlhs == 1) { plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(42.0); }
}
```

Whether one types on matlab prompt `>> mfoo()` or `>> mfoo();`, **it makes no difference**... Indeed, in both cases, matlab equally considers `nlhs` is `0` (see `mexPrintf` debug output) and there is no display for `ans` value.

#### Question

I would like the `mex-code` to behave just like the `m-code` does.

So far, I removed the test `if (nlhs == 1)` before to assign `plhs[0]` ... and it works ... but is it 100% safe to do so in all situations ; normally `nlhs == 0` so accessing `plhs[0]` should not be ok, right ? ... it's weird ... maybe there's a safer approach ? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/data-flow-in-mex-files.html

> Note:   It is possible to return an output value even if nlhs = 0, which corresponds to returning the result in the ans variable.